# UITextfield not able to see text and cursor while rotating iPhone device to landscape when the keyboard is up

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In `UITextfield` not able to see text and cursor while rotating iPhone device to landscape when the keyboard is up.

The text in `UITextfield` is not displaying once we tap on return button in keyboard or if we type then it is showing

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `UITextFieldDelegate` Methods and have to set frame of textfield and move it as per requirements because when device is in landscope mode may be your textfield will be hide under keyboard.

Comment: i am able to see uitextfield but not text in that